# fragment with UI using setRetainInstance(true)

Tags: android, android-fragments

To handle the orientation change in my application i am using `setRetainInstance(true)` on my fragment.These fragments are not headless fragment they have a ui. so the android UI says the fragement that is attached to a view causes memory leaks when `setRetainInstance` is set true. Now my question is that can i prevent this memory leak by setting `setRetainInstance` as false when i am moving to the next fragemnt?

That is when a button is click to move to the next fragment i set this fragment as `setRetainInstance(false)`. can this prevent the memory leak?

Comment: I think that will be a clever trick if it can prevent memory leaks. But make sure you call it in `onDestroy` because onStop will also be called on orientation change and `setRetainInstace` method will have no advantage in that case.

Comment: "so the android UI says the fragement that is attached to a view causes memory leaks when setRetainInstance is set true" -- that is not strictly true. There will be a memory leak between the time of the configuration change and when the fragment is shown again (and, hence, is called with `onCreateView()`). So long as you ensure that by the end of `onCreateView()` that you are no longer holding onto references to the old activity or its widgets, the leak will end at that point.

Comment: @CommonsWare if the leak would end when the `onCreateView()` is called then i think there is non problem in using the `setRetainInstance(true)` in fragments with UI. also should i call `setRetainInstance(false)` when moving to next fragment ? is there any advantage if i set 'setRetainInstance' false?

Comment: "if the leak would end when the onCreateView() is called then i think there is non problem in using the setRetainInstance(true) in fragments with UI" -- I agree, with the caveat that developers do make mistakes. "also should i call setRetainInstance(false) when moving to next fragment ?" -- I have never tried this, sorry.